# Retrieve country from Facebook SDK - IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK to get user's details with permissions:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"user_photos",@"public_profile",@"user_location", @"user_birthday",nil];
```

I know how to get the city but how can I get user's country?

```
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;

         NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];
         NSString *name = userData[@"name"];
         NSString *city = userData[@"location"][@"name"];
     }
     else
     {
         //...
     }
 }];
```

Comment: try `[@"location"][@"country"]`. All you need is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/?locale=en

Comment: Thanks man, but it return as nil =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `[@"location"][@"country"]` as @trick14 outlined. If you can't get a value from it, it can have multiple reasons:

- The user you're querying has no location information in his profile
- The Access Token you're using has no granted `user_location` permission (Check with a call to `/me/permissions`)
- There's no country info for the location (quite unlikely)

You have a problem with your permissions string BTW, `user_location` is contained twice, and `offline_access` and `publish_stream` are deprecated long ago.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSString *city = userData[@"location"][@"city"];
```

[See here for more info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/locations).. :)